# Retrieve Google place id using Google+ URL

Tags: google-places-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve a place_id with just a url to a business [like so.](https://plus.google.com/102116136799532946769/about) I have the URL, which has a google plus ID inside the URL string, but I need the place id. I've tried searching via [Google+ People:Get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get), which returns the business, but not the place id. I've searched extensively through the Places API for a solution, and have found nothing.

Is this possible through Google's APIs? They have two separate references and ids to the same place, and I'm not really sure why. I feel like it should be possible, and maybe I'm just missing something.